# How do I use results from one Command into a WHERE clause of another Command?

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I have 2 different JDBC connections.

The first JDBC Command gives me back almost all the data I need to build my report.

I created a second JDBC Command to another database, but in the Where Clause, I would like to use the result values from the first Command.

Could this be done?

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes this can be done...

take a sub report and use second JDBC connection.. now link main report and sub report..

link the reports with the fields that produce the results from first command and then use the linked fields in `Record Selection Formula` of the sub report.